# Should we allow the quick and dirty answer that merely links to an offsite resource?

Tags: discussion, answers

Here's a [real world example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/explanation-of-the-story-ending-of-limbo/6330#6330) of what was the subject of discussion today on Chat -- the discussion was not on this particular question and answer couple, be warned.

I'm not asking if it is a good answer or if it should be upvoted. I'm asking if it should be merely allowed to exist on this website.

Comment: This question is the result of an argument on chat between me and Arda Xi. [Start of relevant transcript.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/126552)

Comment: This is mostly covered by http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/559/whats-the-policy-regarding-easy-questions, I imagine, as those are the kinds of questions that would get such answers. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-we-link-to-content-or-contain-content also concerns some discussion about our own policy with linking content.

Comment: Also, couldn't you have picked an example that wasn't a subjective list question to start with?

Comment: @Grace -- Fixed

Comment: FYI, I have made your example a bit obsolete by editing my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with badp that they should be allowed as they technically answer the question, however it should be encouraged to provide information on **this** site (without violating copyrights!) due to link-rot.

Furthermore, providing an excerpt helps others judge the quality of your link, without having to actually visit the site, because they know from the excerpt that it is in fact correct.

So while they should be allowed, based on my experiences on Super User though, I highly recommend everyone to add more info than just a link, since it **will** cost you potential upvotes

Answer (score 3):

yes we should. [This answer on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/9758#9758) explains in length why this is a good idea.

Comment: How fitting. [ ](http://o/~)

Comment: while I don't mean to take sides in this discussion I would like to point out that the answer you linked is really in reference to a different problem.  While it is partially applicable, she was commenting on fast answers as opposed to slow answers, not fast dirty answers as compared to slower clean answers.